# How to insert text in image using Rastermaster Snow?

Tags: java

I need to insert file name in file image. We are using RasterMaster Snow API for this. I came to know that we can insert text in image using annotation merge. But could not found any help how to use Snow annotation to merge text in image. Below is the code snippet, however not working.

It does generate the `test1.tiff` image without exception, but it does not insert file name in the generated image. It seems that I am not using snow annotation merge functionality correctly.

```
try {

         File source= new File("D:\\rastermaster\\test1.pdf");
         File result = new File("D:\\rastermaster\\test1.tiff");


        Snowbnd snowbnd = new Snowbnd();
        Snow.SANN_RECT sn = new Snow.SANN_RECT();
        sn.left=1200;
        sn.right=1200;
        sn.top=1200;
        sn.bottom=1200;
        Snow.SANN_POINT p1 = new Snow.SANN_POINT();
        p1.x=12;
        p1.y=12;
        Snow.SANN_POINT p2 = new Snow.SANN_POINT();
        p2.x=102;
        p2.y=102;


        Snow.SANN_POINT pn[] = new Snow.SANN_POINT[]{p1,p2};

        int status = snowbnd.IMG_decompress_bitmap(source.getAbsolutePath(), 0);
       // snowbnd.IMGLOW_set_bitmap_name("BT-7208_file_name", "BT-7208");
        //snowbnd.IMGLOW_set_print_header("BT-7208_file_name", "BT-7208",1); snowbnd
        snowbnd.IMGLOW_set_pdf_output((int) PD4Constants.A4.getWidth(), (int) PD4Constants.A4.getHeight());


        SnowAnn sann = new SnowAnn(200, 300);
      //  Sann = new SnowAnn(Simage.getWidth(),Simage.getHeight()); 

      //Set the size and position of the rectangle using 
        sann.SANN_set_croprect(120, 120, 120, 120); 

      //add text using 
        sann.SANN_add_object(3, sn, "file_name".getBytes(), pn, "file_name".length()); 
        //sann.textString="hello";
      //if you wish to view the annotation use 
        //sann.SANN_display_annotations(grp, f, status, status, status, status); 

      //burn the annotation into the file using 
        int status2 =sann.SANN_merge_annotations(snowbnd, null);
        status = snowbnd.IMG_save_bitmap(result.getAbsolutePath(), 16);


        if (status < 0) {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            re.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Error err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Would you expand on your description of "not working"? Do you get any errors? Does part of it work?

Comment: @halfer, it works and generate test1.tiff image without exception, But it does not insert file name in the generated image. It seems that I am not using snow annotation merge functionality correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In below line of code

```
 sann.SANN_add_object(3, sn, "file_name".getBytes(), pn, "file_name".length());
```

it need to pass 13 instead of 3 as the first argument.

```
 sann.SANN_add_object(13, sn, "file_name".getBytes(), pn, "file_name".length());
```

When we give a value of 3, it ignore the value of object(text we need to insert) being passed to be insert.Also value of Snow.SANN_POINT[] array passed as argument to sann.SANN_add_object(......) array can be null(At least I Don't know it's use).

```
File source= new File("D:\\demo\\test.pdf");
File result = new File("D:\\demo\\test.tif");
Snowbnd snowbnd = new Snowbnd();
snowbnd.IMGLOW_set_license_path("path of licence");
int status = snowbnd.IMG_decompress_bitmap(source.getAbsolutePath(), 0);
Snow.SANN_RECT sn = new Snow.SANN_RECT();
sn.left=0;
sn.right=600;
sn.top=0;
sn.bottom=20;
SnowAnn sann = new SnowAnn(snowbnd.getWidth(), snowbnd.getHeight());
sann.SANN_set_croprect(0, 0, 200, 600);
sann.ann_font_height=1;
sann.ann_bold=1;
sann.SANN_set_fcolor(0,0,0);
sann.SANN_add_object(13, sn, "file_name".getBytes(), null, "file_name".length());
int status2 =sann.SANN_merge_annotations(snowbnd, null);
status = snowbnd.IMG_save_bitmap(result.getAbsolutePath(), 16);
```